# Какая разница между std::string, char [] и char *

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, указатели

В чем отличие между:

```
char s[] = "text";
char* ps = "text1";
std::string str = "text3";
```

И что лучше использовать?

Comment: Молоток, киянка, кувалда... Что лучше использовать? Кстати, строка 2 неверна - это указатель на *константную* строку, `const char* ps = "text1";`.

Comment: В С++ лучше использовать `std::string` если нет причин перейти на более низкий уровень. А вообще лучше - понятие субьективное.

Comment: Ну, проблема в том, что в `std::string` и вообще в `stl` много подводных камней. На первый взгляд кажется, что использовать `std::string` проще, чем массивы символов, но в чуть сценарии использования усложняются, начинаются странные вылеты и плавающие баги. Вот и универсальная причина перейти на более низкий уровень - с инкапсуляцией в C++ плохо.

Answer (score 5):

1.

```
char s[] = "text";
```

Объявление массива `s` типа `char []` и инициализация этого массива строковым литералом `"text"`. Т. е. `s` — это просто массив из **пяти** символов: `t`, `e`, `x`, `t`, `\0`.

Вы можете менять его:

```
s[0] = 'n'; /* s: "next" */
```

Но не можете переприсвоить сам массив `s` (это же массив):

```cpp
char s[] = "text";  /* OK */
s = "another text"; /* Это ошибка. */
```

2.

```
char *s = "text"; /* до C++11 */
const char *s = "text"; /* начиная C++11 */
```

Объявление указателя `s` типа `char *` и присваивание ему указателя на первый элемент строкового литерала `"text"`. Попытка изменить этот строковой литерал (`s[0] = 'a'`, например), — это неопределенное поведение.

Однако сам указатель переприсваивать можно:

```
const char *p = "text"; /* OK */
p = "another text"; /* OK */
```

Начиная с C++11 строковые литералы могут быть прямо присвоены только `const char *` (т. е. только указателям на *константный* `char`).

3.

```
std::string s = "text";
```

Создание объекта `s` класса `std::string` и присваивание ему `const char *`<sup>1</sup>. Т. е. `s` — это не массив и не указатель, а объект.

Класс строк в свою очередь содержит множество различных возможностей: копирование, сравнение, конкатенация, изменение, поиск подстрок и так далее. Чего строки в стиле C (массивы), конечно лишены (если не принимать во внимание `<cstring>`).

---

> Что лучше использовать?

Использовать нужно то, что больше подходит для конкретной задачи. У каждой обговоренной выше «строки» есть свои области применения.

---

1. Выполняется неявное приведение типов: присваивается не `const char [N]`, что является типов для всех строковых литералов, а именно указатель. Также см. [оператор присваивания](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/) класса строк.

Answer (score 0):

1. Руководствуясь [Cpp core guidlines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines), могу сказать: `std:string`
   следует использовать для осмысленных текстовых строк, т.е. там, где
   символы в сумме представляют собой слова, предложения, выражения и
   т.д. Массивы `char` используются, когда необходимо представить
   отдельно стоящие символы, конкатенация которых не имеет смысла (речь идёт о том, как **стоит** делать, это отнюдь не говорит, что так делается повсеместно).
2. Насчёт разницы между `char*` и `char[]` крайне советую почитать [здесь](http://dkhramov.dp.ua/Comp.CharLiteralsAndArrays#.XVVOtegzaUk). Если коротко: `char*` указатель на константную строку, а `char[]` – изменяемый массив символов.

Comment: `char[]` — это вообще не указатель.

Comment: @eanmos Согласен, неверно выразился

Comment: Почему неизменяемый-то?)

Comment: @eanmos Потому что заработался я уже :)

Comment: @eanmos Спасибо за правки

Comment: Да не за что...)

Answer (score 0):

Первое - массив символов фиксированного размера, по-видимому, в стеке (если вы не объявили его как глобальный).

Второе - указатель на строку, зразмещенную где-то в памяти (куда компилятор положит). Изменять ее нельзя, можно только указать на другую строку.

Класс строки, который поддерживает массу функций, и хранит строку где-то (вероятнее всего, в динамической памяти, но может короткие хранить и в своем внутреннем буфере).

А дальше - зависит от того, для чего вы хотите использовать ее.

Comment: Второе это указатель на массив `char`, как и `std::string`, в общем-то. Строк в C++ вообще нет.